# where is org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.HttServletResponse?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, catalina

This is insane, but which package (artifact) holds `org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.HttServletResponse`?
Is it obsolete? I can import `org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.HttpServletRequest` just fine.

I already have as dependencies (trying them one at a time in a desperate hope)

> org.apache.tomcat.tomcat-catalina
>
> org.apache.tomcat.tomcat-servlet-api
>
> org.apache.tomcat.tomcat-coyote
>
> org.apache.tomcat.tomcat-util
>
> org.apache.catalina.catalina
>
> org.apache.tomcat.tomcat-annotations-api

EDIT:

I would like to implement a **[HandlerInterceptorAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)** in order to execute custom logic on each request and potentially redirect. The preHandle() method accepts HttpServletResponse as a second argument. The `javax` one is not accepted (the method doesn't override its super class counterpart in this case).

```
import org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.HttpServletRequest;
//import org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.HttServletResponse; //cannot find symbol
import org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.ServletMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         Object handler) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Based on the name I'd suspect it's some preview version for a Servlet 4.0 specification class. Yup. [Provides early access to some parts of the Servlet 4.0 API](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/servlet4preview/http/HttpServletRequest.html). What do you need it for?

Comment: Seems there's no preview interface for `HttpResponse`, presumably there's no new functionality for the response. But you should not be using that interface anyway, why aren't you using the standard `javax.*` interfaces?

Comment: Method preHandle() is defined with org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview. What interface do you think I can use instead of HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Comment: No it isn't. Spring would never use an internal Tomcat interface. I don't know how you stumbled upon importing that package, but you should be using the `javax.*` packages.